# Execute C++ code in R

Tags: c++, r

I am trying to execute c++ function using boost library in R. I've also installed boost header file package (BH). When I try to execute the code it give me the following error:

```
src <- '
  #include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp> 
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {     
boost::math::binomial_coefficient<double>(25, i);
}'
sillyExp <- cfunction(signature(), src, convention = ".C")
```

Where I am going wrong?

Edit: Following is the error

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language, verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! file68b0697546bd.cpp:11:54: fatal error: boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp> 
                                                      ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: file68b0697546bd.o] Error 1
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="file68b0697546bd.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file68b0697546bd.o"' had status 2
```

Comment: What error did it give you?

Comment: When I add `library(inline)` to your code in order to make `cfunction` known, I get a different error message. Please show us your real code plus error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to execute some C++ code, then you can use `Rcpp::evalCpp`:

```
Rcpp::evalCpp("boost::math::binomial_coefficient<double>(25, 3)", 
              depends="BH", 
              include="#include <boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp>")
#> [1] 2300
```